# Can't build because I can't run the designer because I can't build

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2008, inheritance

Seemingly a vicious circle here. I've just taken on a project that won't build. The reason it won't build is because I have a lot of "does not exist in the current context" errors with regards to controls that definitely would exist in the current context if I could view the forms in design mode. But I can't view them in design mode because they inherit from a class that inherits from Form that seems to be causing a problem.

Now, I thought the problem may have been that the class that inherits from Form may have been accidentally tampered with as it had the form icon in the solution explorer but should have been just the standard .cs file. So I 'broke it out' of that context and put it in a new .cs file (as explained somewhere else on another SO thread). So I'm stuck here now, don't know what to do.

Error message:

**The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: frmMain --- The base class 'MyCustomForm.MyCustomForm' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.**

Comment: So you don't have a missing dll reference someplace in your solution? Under the "References" folder it will show it with a yellow caution sign if there is a problem.  My guess is that you are missing some 3rd party installs or dependencies.

Comment: No it seems that all of the references are working. No errors or strange icons are appearing.

Comment: Can the class inheriting from Form be opened in the designer. Note: If it has generic type parameters it will not work, even if the final form resolves all there parameters.

Comment: No easy way out of this situation, I'm afraid. Can you access the .Designer.cs file? Usually there's enough information there for you to manually rebuild the form - check especially the InitializeComponent method on that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out all of the code that uses those controls, build your project, then uncomment them.

Comment: It would take me a long long time to do this, there's hundreds of these errors, I'm not sure this is the solution!? I may try it if I don't get another feasible suggestion but you may be right.

Comment: @SkonJeet: Just comment out the whole class.

Comment: Thanks again SLaks, the 'headache' about it is that there's a few forms that inherit from MyCustomForm so it's going to have to be done right across the project, nevermind, I'm just hoping this works...

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging Visual Studio using a second instance of Visual Studio.
1. Launch first instance of Visual Studio, and load your project. Don't open the designer yet.
2. Launch a second instance of Visual Studio, and select **Debug/Attach To Process** on the menu to start debugging the first instance of Visual Studio (devenv.exe). Make sure the Output Window is visible, and ensure that enable catching exceptions.
3. In the original instance of Visual Studio, open the Form designer for the Form that is giving you problems.
4. In the second instance of Visual Studio, watch the Output Window and handle any exceptions that occur. This may give you enough information to see what is going wrong.